# Laravel Factory Create for Each Not Isolated Between the Same Factory Invocations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I would have thought that factory creation was isolated so I could do:

```
factory(Ctow\User::class, 5)->each(function($user) { 
  // Add relations to 5 users created
});
factory(Ctow\User::class, 5)->each(function() { 
  // Add different relations to 5 different users created
  // and not include the previously created users
  // in the iteration
});
```

But performing this in a seed:

```
factory(Ctow\User::class)->create(['username' => 'test1@example.com']);
factory(Ctow\User::class)->create(['username' => 'test2@example.com']);
factory(Ctow\User::class)->create(['username' => 'test3@example.com']);

factory(Ctow\User::class)
    ->create(['username' => 'final@example.com'])
    ->each(function ($user) {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info('USER', [$user->username]);
    });
```

Results in output from seeding seen below, but I would have thought it would only include a single record `final@example.com`, and not the previous created users:

```
// Actual Result
[2019-02-17 22:52:05] local.INFO: USER ["test1@example.com"] 
[2019-02-17 22:52:05] local.INFO: USER ["test2@example.com"] 
[2019-02-17 22:52:06] local.INFO: USER ["test3@example.com"] 
[2019-02-17 22:52:06] local.INFO: USER ["final@example.com"]
```

```
// Expected Result
[2019-02-17 22:52:06] local.INFO: USER ["final@example.com"]
```

If you do this in different seed files it has the same result so it occurs across files based on the factory used, as well as, locally.  Also, occurs when created using associated factory states.

Is there a way to isolate adding relationships between the same factories invocations without this occurring? So I can create users that have no related models, and then add relations to only a few specific ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13534#issuecomment-218947319) is don't use `each` on a single model creation as it delegates to the builder since a model doesn't have the `each` method.